# How to add "Open with Code" with right-click in Ubuntu or Pop OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

In windows OS, when we install VS-Code, the option to add "open with code" is offered to us. But I couldn't find it in Ubuntu or Pop-OS!
Thus, I'd like to know, is there any way I can add "open with code" when I right-click within a folder to open the folder in VS-Code?

Although, we can use a terminal for opening the directory in VS-Code using "code ." but I'm looking for the right-click of the mouse.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: did you see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/873#issuecomment-610302389) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could manually write down MIME types associated with vscode in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` like this

```
[Added Associations]
text/html=code.desktop
text/css=code.desktop
text/javascript=code.desktop
```

Assuming you have a proper `Desktop Entry` inside `/usr/share/applications/`

---

You can also try this `Nautilus` extension (if you use `Nautilus`)

https://github.com/harry-cpp/code-nautilus

This will install it if you use `bash`

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harry-cpp/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: The perfect method is this; no third-party scripts!

Comment: However, mine is located here; `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 16):

You can run this command in the terminal

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cra0zy/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```

After that you'll see on right click 'Open in Code'!

Works perfectly in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 22.04 too

Answer (score 0):

Go to Template directory under Home, click on Activities in the top left and and search for "Text Editor", then create an empty document naming it as "Text Editor" and save it in the Template Directory. Then you are done!!. Enjoy
[image].